# How to change seekbar value in kotlin

Tags: java, android, android-studio, kotlin, seekbar

[image: TickSeekBar image]

I referenced this https://github.com/warkiz/TickSeekBar

I want to change `0 33 57 100` values in the photo to `2 4 6 8`

And I want to show that value as a log

I've tried several values but couldn't make it work.

```html
      <com.warkiz.tickseekbar.TickSeekBar
            android:id="@+id/tsb1"
            android:layout_width="286dp"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            app:tsb_ticks_count="4"
            app:tsb_thumb_color="@color/skyblue"
            app:tsb_thumb_size="16dp"
            app:tsb_show_tick_marks_type ="oval"
            app:tsb_tick_marks_color="@color/skyblue"
            app:tsb_tick_marks_size="8dp"
            app:tsb_show_tick_texts="below"
            app:tsb_tick_texts_color="@color/black"
            app:tsb_tick_texts_size="17sp"
            app:tsb_track_background_color="@color/divid_color"
            app:tsb_track_background_size="2dp"
            app:tsb_track_progress_color="@color/skyblue"
            app:tsb_track_progress_size="3dp"
            android:layout_marginTop="90dp"
            android:layout_marginLeft="40dp"/>
```

```html
       val seekBar = TickSeekBar
            .with(context!!)
            .max(7F)
            .min(1F)
            .progressValueFloat(true)
            .progress(33f)
            .tickCount(7)
            .showTickMarksType(TickMarkType.DIVIDER)
            .tickMarksColor(resources.getColor(R.color.skyblue))
            .tickMarksSize(6) //dp
            .tickTextsSize(13) //sp
            .showTickTextsPosition(TextPosition.ABOVE)
            .tickTextsColorStateList(resources.getColorStateList(R.color.skyblue))
            .thumbColor(Color.parseColor("#ff0000"))
            .thumbSize(14)
            .trackProgressColor(resources.getColor(R.color.colorAccent))
            .trackProgressSize(4)
            .trackBackgroundColor(resources.getColor(R.color.skyblue))
            .trackBackgroundSize(2)
            .build()
```

Answer (score 0):

Set the max value to 8. That will solve your issue.

```
<com.warkiz.tickseekbar.TickSeekBar
        ...
        app:tsb_max="8"/>
```

[image]

Answer (score 0):

In the xml file, add these two lines:

```
<com.warkiz.tickseekbar.TickSeekBar
        ...
        app:tsb_min="2"
        app:tsb_max="8"/>
```

[image: seekBar image]

And to get the value as a `Log`, do this in the Kotlin file:

```
var tickSeekBar: TickSeekBar = findViewById(R.id.tsb1)
tickSeekBar.onSeekChangeListener =
    object : OnSeekChangeListener {
        override fun onSeeking(seekParams: SeekParams?) {
        }

        override fun onStartTrackingTouch(seekBar: TickSeekBar?) {
        }

        override fun onStopTrackingTouch(seekBar: TickSeekBar?) {
            if (seekBar != null) {
                Toast.makeText(applicationContext, seekBar.progress.toString(), Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show()
                Log.d("abc", seekBar.progress.toString())
            }
        }
    }
```